# Proof on the norm of an operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

> Let $\vert \vert \cdot \vert \vert $ be a norm in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Show that
> $$ \vert \vert x \vert \vert = \sup\{A(x) : A \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^{n}, \mathbb{R}), \vert \vert A \vert \vert \leq 1 \}.$$

My idea is to show that the equality holds proving both inequalties. The $\geq$ one is easy to prove, by I don't know how to prove the other one. I thought about using Hans-Banach theorem, but I can't see how to get it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be any non-zero vector and let $M$ be the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $x$. Define $A(cx)=c\|x\|$. This defines a linear map on $M$ with norm $1$.   By Hahn - Banach Theorem there exists a linear map from  $\mathbb R^{n}$  to $\mathbb R$ which extends this map without increasing the norm. But $\|A\| =1$ so the extended linear map $B$ has norm $1$.   Can you finish?

Comment: Nothing in the question says that the norm arises from an inner product.

Comment: @asahay Thanks. I have edited.